# Rows to a single column based on sequence and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

> Blockquote

Table structure:

| PK_ID | FK_ID | SEQUENCE | TEXT | CREATEDATE | UPDATEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1233456 | 5895552 | 1 | This is | 12-JAN-22 | 13-JAN-22 |
| 1233457 | 5895552 | 2 | a SQLL | 12-JAN-22 | 13-JAN-22 |
| 1233458 | 5895552 | 1 | This is | 13-JAN-22 | 14-JAN-22 |
| 1233459 | 5895552 | 2 | a SQL | 13-JAN-22 | 14-JAN-22 |
| 1233460 | 5895552 | 1 | This is | 14-JAN-22 | 15-JAN-22 |
| 1233461 | 5895552 | 2 | a SQL.com | 14-JAN-22 | 15-JAN-22 |
| 1233462 | 5895552 | 1 | This is | 15-JAN-22 |  |
| 1233463 | 5895552 | 2 | a SQLcom | 15-JAN-22 |  |

Grouping the text based on the `sequence` and `createdate` (`Updatedate` NULL represents it the current record) and ordered by `createdate`.

Tried using `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` works well when no date is there, but I'm not able to generate the needed output as the grouping based on the date is not generating the needed output

Expected output:

| FK_ID | TEXT | CREATEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5895552 | This is a SQLL | 12-JAN-22 |
| 5895552 | This is a SQL | 13-JAN-22 |
| 5895552 | This is a SQL.com | 14-JAN-22 |
| 5895552 | This is a SQLcom | 15-JAN-22 |

Comment: select string_agg(text, ' ') within group (order by sequence)
, fk_id, createdate
from yourtable
group by fk_id, createdate

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned SQL is 2016, string_agg is not a recognized built in function

Comment: you should add it to the tag (or text)

Comment: I just did as text but will add the tag as well

Comment: Could the FK_ID ever have more than 2 sequence per createdate?

Comment: @Isolated yes it can

Answer (score 1):

You can do the old school `for xml`:

```sql
with data as (
select *
from (
    VALUES  (1233456, 5895552, 1, N'This is', N'12-JAN-22', N'13-JAN-22')
    ,   (1233457, 5895552, 2, N'a SQLL', N'12-JAN-22', N'13-JAN-22')
    ,   (1233458, 5895552, 1, N'This is', N'13-JAN-22', N'14-JAN-22')
    ,   (1233459, 5895552, 2, N'a SQL', N'13-JAN-22', N'14-JAN-22')
    ,   (1233460, 5895552, 1, N'This is', N'14-JAN-22', N'15-JAN-22')
    ,   (1233461, 5895552, 2, N'a SQL.com', N'14-JAN-22', N'15-JAN-22')
    ,   (1233462, 5895552, 1, N'This is', N'15-JAN-22', '')
    ,   (1233463, 5895552, 2, N'a SQLcom', N'15-JAN-22', '')
) t (PK_ID,FK_ID,SEQUENCE,TEXT,CREATEDATE,UPDATEDATE)
)
select fk_id, createdate
, stuff((select ' ' + text from data d2 where d2.fk_id = d.fk_id and d2.createdate = d.createdate order by sequence for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS x
from data d
group by fk_id, createdate
```

Output:

| fk_id | createdate | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5895552 | 12-JAN-22 | This is a SQLL |
| 5895552 | 13-JAN-22 | This is a SQL |
| 5895552 | 14-JAN-22 | This is a SQL.com |
| 5895552 | 15-JAN-22 | This is a SQLcom |

The important part is when you generate the XML, you need to join back on the original table so you get correct values.